# Connect to an lt2p VPN client

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, port-forwarding

I've run into an issue that may be related to several different posts, but I'm not sure what the actual process is or where to even start.

Currently, I have successfully set up a VPN with xl2tpd/strongswan following the steps in this [tutorial](https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn/blob/master/docs/clients.md#configure-linux-vpn-clients-using-the-command-line). What I would like to do, is take specific ports from other servers (not the client VPN) and forward them to specific ports and IPs onto the client VPN with the intent to access specific shared folders. The topology should look like

```
+-------------------+             +---------------------+
|                   |             |                     |
|  server1          |             |          server2    |
|                   |             |                     |
|            port1  |             |   port1      port2  |
+-----------------+-+             +----+----------+-----+
                  |                    |          |
                  |                    |          |
                  |                    |          |
                  |       +------------+          |
                  |       |                       |
                  |       |      +----------------+
           port_1 |       |      | port_2
              +---+-------+------+-+
              |         port_1     |
              |                    |
              |    VPN client      |
              |                    |
              |                    |
              +-+-------------+----+
                |             |
                |             |
                |             |
                |             |
              +-+-------------+----+
              | port_x      port_y |
              |                    |
              |    VPN server      |
              |                    |
              |                    |
              +--------------------+
```

I have researched the following answers and sites (and more), but they don't seem to help, however, these sites I believe are the most relevant to my problem:

- [advanced routing how-to](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.netfilter.html)
- [simple port forwarding](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320121/simple-port-forwarding)
- [port forwarding to a VPN client](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/432175/port-forwarding-to-vpn-client?rq=1).

It may be apparent that I'm brand new to this, so I may be mixing terminology and I know that at the moment I am pretty ignorant when it comes to this type of networking.

Comment: Since you just set up the VPN, it would make more sense to use a non-IPsec VPN server, as IPsec VPNs are [generally] not efficient - WireGuard generally outperforms all VPN types, with OpenVPN _(an SSL VPN)_ almost always coming in second _(OpenVPN almost always outperforms an IPsec VPN provided the configs are tuned and not generic ones copied/pasted - tuned [examples](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenVPN))_